# "$((A\times B) \to C)$" denotes what?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm having some trouble understanding notation. The question is

> For any three sets $A,B,C$ ,
>   $((A\times B) \to C) =_c (A \to (B\to
>  C))$

Exactly what does "$((A\times B) \to C)$" denote? Is it the set of all mappings from $A\times B$ to $C$? Or just *a* mapping?

I found this in Yiannis Moschovakis "Notes on set Theory".

Comment: "Please remember to mention where (book, paper, webpage, etc.) you encountered any mathematical notation you are asking about." As it is we can't really know. It's probably the set of mappings, or the type, or...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry about that. I've edited the question new. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What does the $=_c$ mean? Equal cardinality?

Comment: Surely the book has a page somewhere whereon nomenclature is defined.

Comment: This is explained in the 1st page [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.brandeis.edu%2F~igusa%2FMath101b%2Fhom.pdf&ei=I9NWU_iTFcKKyASKz4GQAQ&usg=AFQjCNFDs29KpIIUrwK4xFIld80-m4uAPg&bvm=bv.65177938,d.aWw).

Answer (score 5):

In this context, it seems to be the set of all mappings, which you can see because on the right of the equation you have $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$, and this wouldn't really make sense if $B \rightarrow C$ were a single mapping. I think $B \rightarrow C$ is usually written $C^B$. This 'equation' is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a function, where if we take a function $f(a, b) = \phi_{a,b}$ with two arguments, we can turn it into a function $g(a)$ which yields a function $g_a(b) = \phi_{a,b}$. It can be expressed with a [universal property in the category of sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object).

Answer (score 3):

The notation $X \to Y$ usually denotes the *type* of functions which has domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. In context of set theory, that would be just the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$, sometimes written also as $Y^X$ or ${}^XY$ to avoid order confusion (note the inversion in the first).

Hence, using the alternate notation, $A \times B \to C$ is $C^{A \times B}$, and $A \to (B \to C)$ is $(C^B)^A$.
The similarity with property of real numbers $(c^b)^a = c^{a\cdot b}$ is not a coincidence.

Relevant operations are commonly known as [currying and uncurrying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), should you have problems, you can check below.

Currying:

> \begin{align}\mathrm{curry}(f) = x \mapsto y \mapsto f(x,y),\end{align}
>
>  or in different notation,
>
>  \begin{align}\mathrm{curry}(f)(x)(y) = f(x,y).\end{align}

Uncurrying:

> \begin{align}\mathrm{uncurry}(f) = (x,y) \mapsto f(x)(y),\end{align}
>  or written in the alternate way,
>  \begin{align}\mathrm{uncurry}(f)(x,y) = f(x)(y).\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

On page 15, around the middle you can find the following:

> **$2.22$. Definition.** For any two sets $A$, $B$, $$(A\to B)=_{df}\{f\mid f\colon A\to B\}=\text{ the set of all functions from }A\text{ to }B.$$

So $(A\times B\to C)=_c(A\to(B\to C))$ simply means that the set of functions from $A\times B$ to $C$ has the same cardinality as the set of functions from $A$, to functions from $B$ to $C$.

The last set, $(A\to(B\to C))$ is a set of functions $f\colon A\to(B\to C)$ such that $f(a)$ is a function from $B$ to $C$.

(The question you asked if problem $\rm x2.7$.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the symbols $A \times B \to C$ denote a specific mapping from the Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$ to $C$. It could be that the author means that setting parentheses around it should denote the *set* of all mappings $A \times B \to C$. That is, in more standard notation $(A \times B \to C) = \hom(A\times B, C)$.

It is a standard fact that $\hom(A \times B, C) = \hom(A, \hom(B,C)$ (can you see why?)

This is exactly the statement in your question, *if* setting parentheses around "something" denotes the set of all such "something".

Comment: Regarding "That is, in more standard notation": I doubt that $\mathrm{hom}(A \times B, C)$ is a standard notation in _set theory_.